# Linux ODBC PostgreSQL Drivers

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, odbc, driver

I'm surprised that I can't find any posts with this question as I can't be the only one struggling with this.

I'm trying to use some open-source software (https://sealreport.org/) that will ultimately require a general connection string to access a Postgres database using an ODBC driver as it is running on a Linux server(CentOS). This whole process is proving quite difficult for me.

1 - https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/ This is the official ODBC driver for Postgres. One should be able to configure - make - make install. However, I am stuck at the configuring stage. I'm running the following command:

```
sudo ./configure --with-libpq=/usr/bin/psql --with-unixodbc=/bin/odbcinst
```

which is returning:

```
configure: error: unixODBC library "odbcinst" not found
```

odbcinst runs, and is clearly in /bin. I have also tried passing in odbc_config which returns the same error.

Thus I am unable to install the driver.

2 - https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/07/31/how-to-configure-unixodbc/ This link gives informs me that there is a fedora package for installing the postgres driver. This seems to work.

```
odbcinst -q -d
```

returns multiple drivers one of which reads:

```
# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

Then

```
cat /etc/odbc.ini
```

returns

```
[Test]
Description= Test Connection
Driver= PostgreSQL
Trace= No
TraceFile= /tmp/psqlodcb.log
Database= name of db
Servername= IP address of db
UserName= postgres
Password= mypassword
Port= 5432
ReadOnly= No
RowVersioning= No
ShowSystemTables= No
Show0idColumn= No
Fake0idIndex = No
ConnSettings=
```

Yet,

```
echo | iusql Test -b
```

returns

```
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

3 - I'm looking for some help generally with a Postgres ODBC driver on Linux. After that, I'm still not sure how even with unixodbc that would translate to the kind of connection string you could pass into an application wanting to use the driver. I'm in over my head here, hoping for some help.

4 - Note: I am aware that Devart produces a Postgres driver which may be simpler, but it should be possible to use an open-source version...

Comment: For 1) Per here [Build](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/unix-compilation.html) it is `odbc_config` you want.  Do `whereis odbc_config` to make sure the location is correct.

Comment: Consider checking the logs of the configure process.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the suggestion. I confirmed, and the path is correct. It doesn't seem to matter that I'm point to the right config file. I wonder if the syntax for chaining --with statements is right... That being said, I think I'm closer with the second approach anyway.

Comment: Try  the configure without the `sudo` there may be a `PATH` issue in play.

Comment: Silly question ... why don't you use the  `postgresql-odbc` package that Centos provides?  `yum install postgresql-odbc` and be done with it?

Comment: @tink That's what I'm trying to do in the second point. I install the package, then I try to add the data source to unixodbc so that I can reference that later when trying to connect to the DB through the application I'm trying to use. unixodbc seems to recognize the driver, but cannot connect with it for a reason I'm unsure of.

Comment: In that case you may want to add your pg_hba.conf, too ... you have verified locally that the postgres instance is operational, using `psql`?

Comment: You haven't found any questions about this here because you're asking on the wrong exchange. Go to https://dba.stackexchange.com/